# Printer installation stalled

Tags: software-installation, printing, freeze

I'm trying to install the drivers for my printer, I think I interrupted the installation first time round and now it just stalls and freezes up. Also when I restart the computer it starts now in "Grub", I think, and is acting up. Other than that its running fine.

What should I do to clear the problem?

Comment: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
I'm getting this now when I try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved the problem, ON MY OWN, I might add! As a Nubie I was well excited!

I found the driver name, on first installing, it asked you which driver you want the Epson one the Ubuntu one or the Standard generic driver. It comes up with its name before you press accept.

Then I remembered the terminal normally sorts stuff out or tells you what code to type or an error code to go and look for/

You experts would probably say "well duh, obviously" but coming from windows you expect the graphical interfaces to work. I typed

```
sudo apt-get install epson-inkjet-printer-nx420
```

Then went back in to Printer Configuration and selected my printer, which was showing up in a handy icon.